# How do I configure nginx to go to a static html page if a php fatal error is detected?

Tags: php, redirect, error-handling, nginx

I have a site that is actively in test with bug-fix development going on. Our dev team is small (2-4 people at times) and the test group is around 25-30 people.  There are a few scripts on our site that deal with accessing a MS ADFS sign on and sometimes in development its not working right because...well, someones testing / fixing it.

I get tons of tickets when this happens. People get a standard error about a file called 'trust.php'. For the moment, it doesn't matter what trust.php does, only that people see a "Server Error" message that says its down for maintenance, and of course they all let me know at once.  Of course I know its a 500 error or some other php error due to a script in trust.php not having a good error handler. but i just need to let the users know that 'we know this is ok, and we're working on it.  We use magento and I know that somewhere in all that zend, varien, and custom code there is some php code without a try-catch. I didn't write it all :)

Barred doing a huge configuration, is there a way i can tell nginx to redirect to a static html file that uses no php when a php error is encountered?  Thanks!

BTW: I will be happy to entertain other solutions, but I need to implement it quickly in the testing environment, if for nothing more than to improve the confidence of the testers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://arnisoft.com/285/nginx-custom-error-handling/

Does this help? I think it just comes down to PHP sending a 500 error downstream to nginx, in which case nginx should be set to serve a file whenever it encounters a 500 error.

Comment: This is exactly the simple solution i was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).